# Best way to share secret keys to integration team

Tags: security, secret-key

Consider I'm going to expose an endpoint for integration purposes which requires a secret key to get authorized. Let say it is going to be x-api-key in request header.

How to share that secret key to another team who is working for integration???... Consider the secret key is generated by the below command.

```
openssl rand -base64 32
```

My concern is not to share the secrets through the mail. Is there any secure way to share the secrets??

Comment: Use an available secure channel that already exists - whatever you have available. If you have none you can still use a physical letter or use the phone.

Comment: @Robert what you mean by secure channel?? and is there any open source tool which can be used ??

Comment: "Secure channel" is a general term for any secure communication method. Please keep in mind that software recommendations are off-topic here as they are usually opinion based.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the suggestion. Where to ask these kinds of questions so that it will be appropriate to gain knowledge

Comment: [Software Recommendations StackExchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Robert Thank you